# How to uninstall the sysdeo plugin

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

Had some strange errors, described here: [lost in deployment: session.getAttribute() returns NULL in some Tomcat configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928446/lost-in-deployment-session-getattribute-returns-null-in-some-tomcat-configurat) and been advised to remove the SysDeo plugin.

Googled on how to remove plugins in Eclipse 3.6, found the plugin in Eclipse Installation Details, still looking for some "uninstall/remove" button. Or should I just remove the files from some of the eclipse sub-folders (contrary to what is written in Eclipse tutorials) and it'll work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help->About>Installation details->Installed software tab

Click on the software that you want to unistall and the "uninstall" button becames enabled. Click that button to uninstall the software.

[image]

**EDIT:** In your comment you say that you installed the plugin by dropping it in the "dropins" folder. Well, according to [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-equinox-p2/), the way to uninstall it would be to just delete it from the "dropins" folder and restart Eclipse.

Comment: I'd wish :) First, the plug-in is found only under "Plug-ins" tab. Second, there is no uninstall button. Third, the appropriate icon is a bit "different". And last (if important) - I've installed it via copying into the dropins folder (just followed the instructions).

Comment: @BreakPhreak If you manually installed it by dropping in the "dropins" folder than it won't show on the installed software tab. Take a look at the edit of my answer on how to uninstall it.